# Transform a list of json value into an array

Tags: json, jq

Is there a way to transform / slurp a list of JSON values into an array ?

The idea is to replicate the functionality of -s / --slurp but for "internal" use.

When we iterate over the values of an array, we get a list of value. I would like to have a way to transform the list back into an array but without enclosing the expression with [ ], without using the array constructor.

I would like it to have the form of a filter. I already tried various things with reduce, foreach and bindings but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

You're asking how to collect the outputs of a stream (list) using something of the form `STREAM | ...`. Unfortunately, that's impossible.

When piping filter `A` into filter `B` as in `A | B`, and `A` happens to output a stream, then `B` is fed with each item of the stream *separately*, i.e. `B` runs as many times as there are items coming from `A`. Therefore no single execution of `B` will be able to see or collect all the (other) items of the stream.<sup>[1]</sup>

The code building the array must necessarily enclose `STREAM`.

- `[ STREAM ]`
- `reduce STREAM as $_ ( []; .+[$_] )`
- `def array( s ): [ s ]; array( STREAM )`
- `ARRAY | map( STREAM )` (An alternative to `[ ARRAY | STREAM ]`.)
- etc

For example,

```sh
jq --slurp .
```

can also be written as

```sh
jq --null-input '[ inputs ]'
```

But there's nothing equivalent that has the following form:

```sh
jq '...'
```

In short, you have an [XY Problem](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341).

---

1. Courtesy of @pmf

Comment: Let me add, when piping from filter `A` into filter `B` as in `A | B` and `A` happens to output a stream, then `B` is fed with each item of the stream **separately**, i.e. `B` runs as many times as there are items coming from `A`. Therefore no single execution of `B` will be able to see or collect all the (other) items of the stream.

Comment: There could be a `B` that `jq` treats specially (e.g. `A | collect`), but no such keyword currently exists (and there's no point in adding one). These two things combined is why it's currently impossible.

Comment: My was XY problem was filtering the key/value pairs of an object. I began with keys [] | filter(...) but then was stuck. I tried to construct incrementally an object but this doesn't seen possible, maybe because of immutability or scoping rules. I have this working solution `jq '[ to_entries [] | select(.key | test("^v")) ] | from_entries' file.json`

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, but you can use `map` as I hinted: [`to_entries | map( select( .key | test("^v") ) ) | from_entries`](https://jqplay.org/s/E5iW4Zm5Bs). And that's equivalent to [`with_entries( select( .key | test("^v") ) )`](https://jqplay.org/s/7A3wMayS2w).

Comment: I disagree that there is no reason to have a `collect` keyword. This is an arbitrary restriction on expressivity for no reason IMO.  We can always do this `[STREAM]` but this does not work for user defined filters. We have filters expressions that can return more than one element in a stream with the comma operator, and yet, we cannot absorb elements with another downstream filter expression. This is a **breaking of the closure property** (which allows us to combine things) which de facto restrict expressivity for no reason. To me this is a language flaw. Or at least an annoying limitation.

Comment: Re "*but this does not work for user defined filters*, Sure it does. jq doesn't care whether a filter is builtin or not.

Comment: Re "*This is an arbitrary restriction on expressivity for no reason IMO.*", It's not an arbitrary restriction. In fact, it's not a restriction at all. As previously mentioned, this is a lack of the addition of major special case to the grammar to cause `|` to mean something other than what it normally does. Saying it's a restriction is like saying it's a restriction that paint doesn't work on water. We can colour water, but it's the fact that paint doesn't do it is not a restriction.

Comment: *but this does not work for user defined filters* : yes `[ user_defined_filter ]` this works. What I meant is that, you can have a filter that take a value and return a stream, but you cannot have a filter that take a stream (as a whole). I guess the solution is to always return arrays

Comment: Yes, you can. `reduce` and `foreach` are examples of builtin ones, and there's an example of a user-defined one in my answer (third bullet). It literally does what you asked, which is to take a stream and produce an array from that stream.

Comment: You cannot use `reduce` or `foreach` to take a stream and return it as an array. You said it yourself if your main answer. And like you said it has to do with `|`. That could be circumvented if we could construct incrementally an array or an object. We'd need proper variables which wouldn't be localized to a pass of a stream

Comment: Re "*You cannot use reduce or foreach to take a stream and return it as an array. You said it yourself if your main answer.*", I said no such thing! Quite the opposite. I showed how it could be done using `reduce`. It can also be done using `foreach`, but it's a lot more complicated than using `reduce`: `foreach ( ( STREAM | [.] ), false ) as $_ ([]; if $_ then .+$_ else . end; if $_ then empty else . end)`

Comment: Re "*That could be circumvented if we could construct incrementally an array or an object.*", That's literally what `reduce` does.

Comment: you cannot do this `jq -n '1,2,3 | [] as $array | reduce . as $e ($array; $array += [$e]) | $array'`, I mean that's the idea, it does not work obviously

Comment: Fixed: [`jq -n 'reduce (1,2,3) as $e ([]; .+[$e])`](https://jqplay.org/s/eEEs4mlRBG)